# Twilio Studio: Possible to call own REST API for recursion?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Is it possible to call your own REST API for the same Twilio Studio Flow in order to run through the flow again but with a decreased counter for example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You just have to `POST` to your REST Api url with the `MAKE HTTPS REQUEST` Widget.